# Null Autowired Fields

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat

Im currently trying to set up my server to use jersey, spring and hibernate on tomcat. At the moment the project builds with maven and deploys on tomcat. When I run in debug mode and call some GET method, the correct @GET method in the com.x.y.z.request package is invoked, but the autowired service class in this class is null and I cant figure out why. I suspect its a configuration problem, but Im a bit new to this and unsure as to where I've gone wrong.

I get this in the console when the server starts

```
....
Sep 13, 2013 11:18:56 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet getContext
INFO: Using default applicationContext
Sep 13, 2013 11:18:56 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.SpringComponentProviderFactory registerSpringBeans
INFO: Registering Spring bean, testRequestService, of type com.x.y.z.TestRequestService as a root resource class
....
```

so it looks like the request bean is being initialized correctly

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/springjee-3.2.xsd    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan
    base-package="com.x.y.z.request, com.x.y.z.service, com.x.y.z.dao" />

<context:annotation-config/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db" />
    <property name="username" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
        <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
     </property>
     <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="serverPersistenceUnit" />
     <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

web.xml (i wrote * as '*' because it was commenting out blocks of text)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">

<display-name>MyWebApp</display-name>

<description>
My Web App
</description>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.x.y.z.request</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/webresources/'*'</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- JAX RS config -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>Jersey Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Trace</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.Redirect</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.ImplicitViewables</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.x.y.z.request</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.feature.FilterForwardOn404</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Jersey Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/'*'</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
<persistence-unit name="serverPersistenceUnit">
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

TestRequestService.java

```
@Component
@Path("/test")
public class TestRequestService 
{
    @Autowired
    private IDelegate delegate;

    @GET
    @Path("{id}") 
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<IObject> get(@PathParam("id") int id)
    {   
         return delegate.get(id);
    } 
}
```

IBusinessDelegate.java

```
@Service
public class Delegate extends AbstractDelegate<IObject> implements IDelegate
{
    @Autowired
    private IDAO<IObject> dao;

    @Override
    public List<IObject> get(int id)
    {
        dao.get(id);
    }
}
```

DAO.java

```
@Repository
public class DAO extends AbstractDAO<IObject> implements IDAO<IObject>
{
    @Override
    public List<IObject> get(int id)
    {
        //some query here
    }
}
```

AbstractDAO.java

```
public abstract class AbstractDAO<T> implements IDAO<T>
{
    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public abstract List<T> get(int id);
}
```

Comment: I've edited and removed the `pom.xml`. We don't need it. Please add your controller that has the injection target (ie `@Autowired` field) and your service class declaration, ie. the class to be autowired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was simply because I was testing with the wrong URL. You can see in my web.xml my servlet-mapping's URL pattern is /webresources/*. If I tested by entering localhost:8080/my-webservice/test/1 into a browser, it would hit my breakpoint in the "/test" request bean, but spring wasn't autowiring the fields (presumably because it's the wrong URL pattern for this jersey/spring servlet). When I began entering localhost:8080/my-webservice/webresources/test/1, everything began working properly. It was a very stupid mistake but I just assumed the URL would be correct if jersey was picking up the requests, maybe someone could shed some light on why this was happening for the wrong URL.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely cause of the problem is that Jersey is not configured to use spring application context to obtain object instances. So Jersey is creating instances of TestRequestSerivce which means that Jersey will ignore the @Autowired becasue it does not understand it.

Did you configure the Jersey servlet to use spring for getting instances of controllers. See 
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example in particular notice that the servlet for jersey should spring aware.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>
                                 com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages
                        </param-name>
            <param-value>com.mkyong.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

Comment: i added my web.xml, im still having the problem